# My workgroup only works one-way

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, workgroup

I created a workgroup containing one desktop computer and four notebooks, all running Windows 7 Ultimate with ESET Smart Security 5 (except for one of the notebooks, which is actually running no antivirus). The network works perfectly, except that the notebook I mentioned above can access the other computers but can't be opened. I had tried removing antivirus, block firewall but nothing has worked. What can it be?

EDIT: This "can't be opened" means the computer cannot be accessed by the others. Indeed, I forgot to explain, if I try opening a shared folder directly like "//COMPUTER/folder" the folder opens, but I can't open the computer itself like "//COMPUTER". Could it be some sort of virus?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by `can't be opened`?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before a few times. usually due to windows firewall, also that the network group is not the same. and sometimes the active network (in network and sharing center) is configured as public rather than home or work.

If you can't open a shared folder but you can ping that computer, try disabling the firewall or open the following ports: TCP 139 and 445, UDP 137 and 138.

Sometimes antivirus replace the default windows firewall and often they are two ways not only filtering the incoming traffic but the outgoing as well. So the problem may be in the source instead of the target computer.